# Why does "document.querySelector('a.some class') [0].href" retun null?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have been advised (here) to use:

```
var nextPageUrl = document.querySelector('a.some class')[0].href;
```

to grab a URL contained within an anchor.
But The Firebug console says it returns null:

> TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

The syntax seems correct and the "somme class" anchor does exist as shown below.

```
<a href="mypage02.html" target="_self" class="some class" title="My Second Page">
```

I tried with

```
var nextPageUrl = document.querySelectorALL('a.some class')[0].href;
```

I then get an "undefined" error.

Many thanks

Comment: you _could_ do: `document.querySelectorAll("a[class='some class']")` if order was important

Comment: Hint: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) *returns null if no matches are found*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `some` and `class` are 2 different classes in the same element you need to use `.some.class`, if you give a space between them it will become a descendant selector.

```
<a href="mypage02.html" target="_self" class="some class" title="My Second Page">
```

there some and class are 2 different classes

```
var nextPageUrl = document.querySelectorAll('a.some.class')[0].href;
```

You are looking for an element with tagname `class` which is a descendant of an anchor with class `some` like

```
<a href="mypage02.html" target="_self" class="some" title="My Second Page">
    <maybe-some-parents>
        <some></some>
    </maybe-some-parents>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.some class` is interpreted as

```
<a class="some">
  <doesn'tMatterHowDeep>
     <class>Only I'm selected</class>
  </doesn'tMatterHowDeep>
</a>
```

Since you're using a space, it is thinking to select an element with the tag name of `class` that is under `a.some`, when actually, they are two different classes.

What you need is `a.some.class`

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your code:

```
document.querySelector()
```

returns a single element, you can't `[0]` on a single element. Use

```
document.querySelectorAll('a.some class')[0].href;
```

instead.

Also, your class names cannot have spaces, every space delimits a new class, so instead of matching `a.some class` match `a[class="some class"]`.

Answer (score 0):

class 'some' and 'class' are now two classes for your code.
class 'some' is OK. But, class with 'class' name is not permitted to use. Its a keyword. So, either make 'some_class' or 'some-class' or 'SomeClass'.

Comment: class is a keyword thats why it can't be used as a class name. Is it so @danish ?